# Is there any simple algorithm to convert a sound source in 3d to volume and panning

Tags: 3d

I'm looking for a simple algorithm which calculates an approximation of volume and pan at the position of the camera from the following 3d data:

- Camera (position and look direction)
- An item which emits mono-audio at a specific position.

Just a basic approximation is enough for this case.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Yes, volume in left and right channel

Answer (score 2):

inverse-square law for distance.  and Blumlein stereo for pan.

Comment: ooops, inverse-square applies to power which is proportional to the square of gain.  so it's just an inverse (a.k.a. "reciprocal") of distance to get the gain coefficient for both left and right.  then a sine-cosine gain (that's the Blumlein thing) for panning left to right.

Comment: So I calculate the distance between the camera and the sound emitter, then I pan the resulting volume according to how it's located relative an imaginary vertical plane pointing in the camera direction?

Comment: appears that you got the idea.  let's assume that the vertical plane is at $\phi=0$ (we call $\phi$ the **azimuth angle**) and that the gain when the emitter is at distance $r_0$ is $G_0$.  so the inverse "square" gain is $$G(r)= G_0\frac{r_0}{r}$$ assuming that the maximum left-right swing is $\pm 45^o$, then the Blumlein gain is $$R(\phi)=\sin(45^o+\phi)$$ and $$L(\phi)=\cos(45^o+\phi)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple, you have to get rid of elevation (z-axis). If you want dead simple with two channels with a fixed range of motion, you can just take the square root of the panning width, normalized between $0$ and $1$:
$$
L = \sqrt{\phi_N} \\
R = \sqrt{1-\phi_N}
$$

where $\phi_N$ is the angle, normalized from $0$ (hard left) to $1$ (hard right). "Turning around" is harder here.

You can also expand the Blumlein idea (equal intensity) to incorporate any number of output channels that are equidistantly spaced on a circle of constant radius.